# How to fix "ProductSelection has no field or association named selectionType" doctrine error

Tags: symfony, caching, doctrine

## Problem:

I read all the similar questions, but it didnt helped me out, so i post another question.
So i write the entity to my database table, and i forgot one field, so i added to the entity, and when i try to use it in my where section i got this error:

`Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: "[Semantical Error] line 0, col 85 near 'type = :type': Error: Class SystemBundle\Entity\ProductSelection has no field or association named type" at /www/csibaf/SymfonyLealkudtuk/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php line 63`

## The Background

I have a table name product_selection. In these i have some field, and i have a product_selection_type field, that i forgot to write in my Entity. So added later and now i got the error.
If i comment out, the where section in my query its perfectly fine and working, but if i place it in again it cause the error. 
I already tried to clear the cahce with `doctrine:clear:cahce-meatadat/query/result` but it dindt helped me. So i checked the memchache and there are disabled. We dont use APC cache either so this isnt the problem. We tried all of this and nothing.
I tried to make another class with a whole different name, but the contetn is the same, just the class name that i changed, and if i cahnge the entity to this in my query builder, its working fine.
Someone were in simillar situation? Or can you get me another suggestion?

## My codes:

### ProductSelection.php

```
namespace SystemBundle\Entity;


use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product_selection")
 **/
class ProductSelection
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="product_selection_id", type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProductAll", inversedBy="selections")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_selection_product_id", referencedColumnName="product_id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     **/
    protected $product;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="product_selection_quantity", type="integer")
     */
    protected $quantity;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="product_selection_price", type="integer")
     */
    protected $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="product_selection_date", type="datetime")
     */
    protected $date;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="ps_user_tracking_source", type="string")
     */
    protected $userTrackingSource;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="product_selection_identify", type="string")
     */
    protected $identify;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserBase")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_selection_userbase_id", referencedColumnName="userbase_id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     **/
    protected $userbase;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="product_selection_type", type="integer")
     */
    protected $type;

        below this just the getters and the setters...
}
```

### QueryBuilder section:

```
$selections = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select('ps')
                ->from('SystemBundle\Entity\ProductSelection', 'ps')
                ->where('ps.product = :id')
                ->andWhere('ps.type = :type')
                ->setParameters(array('id'=>$productId,'type'=>ProductSelectionConstant::NORMAL_CART));
            $selections = $selections->getQuery()
                ->useQueryCache($this->container->getParameter('useQueryCache'))
                ->useResultCache($this->container->getParameter('useResultCache'))
                ->getResult();
```

### My table fields:

```
"PRODUCT_SELECTION_TYPE" NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"PRODUCT_SELECTION_PRODUCT_ID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"PRODUCT_SELECTION_QUANTITY" NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"PRODUCT_SELECTION_PRICE" NUMBER(12,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"PRODUCT_SELECTION_DATE" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"PS_USER_TRACKING_SOURCE" VARCHAR2(69 BYTE), 
"PRODUCT_SELECTION_IDENTIFY" VARCHAR2(32 BYTE), 
"PRODUCT_SELECTION_ID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"PRODUCT_SELECTION_USERBASE_ID" NUMBER(10,0)
```

So if someone can help me out it would be very nice. Thanks a lot.

Comment: did you do a doctrine:schema:update ?

Comment: No i didnt. I have a database from earlier and now i need to refactor the native php code to smyfony, so i cant change the database. And doctrine:schema:update is make a table from entity right? But my table is already exists.

Comment: try no rename your $type "name" to 'type' in the entity...

Comment: I tried it right now with `product_selection_type` and with the camelcase version `productSelectionType` but it didnt helped :(

Comment: Any news on this yet? Code looks fine I guess. Maybe try a rm -rf var/cache Sometimes that does a better job then bin/console ca:cl --env=prod. Did you try to open the same page in the "app_dev.php" page? Like ...yoursite.com/app_dev.php/yourpage page? If it works fine there you can be sure that it is caching.

Comment: Its an api endpoint and its a post call. I tried all clearing stuff but it didnt helped me out. If i cant add in where selection and i dump the entity what i find, in the result the type field is NULL but in my database there is a number (1). So it seems like the orm did not recognize the field. And error not come.